# How to delete all empty lines in a Java project by using the cli?

Tags: bash, sed, command-line-interface

How can I delete all empty lines in all .java files in a project?

By using sed -i '/^\s*$/d' *.java I can delete it in the current dir but how to do the same in all subdirs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GNU's `find` utility.

```
find -type f -name '*.java' -exec sed -i '/^\s*$/d' {} +
```

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting it if you're sure this is what you're looking for.